# Fancy box not opening iFrame second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, modal-window

first post - Hello! I use fancybox ([Fancybox homepage](http://fancybox.net)) to display modal windows.  I'm trying to display a hidden div with an iFrame inside of this div.  Works great.  The second time you click the link, it doesn't load the iFrame (not a 404 error, just there is no content in the iFrame).  Can anyone help?

The important bits:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openIframeLink() {
    $.fancybox({
        'type'          : 'inline',
        'href'          : '#data'
    });
};
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenElement">
    <iframe id="data" src="frames/frame4.php" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: the fancy box is working, its a problem with ur url :) when do u call the `openIframeLink()` you only need fancy box once btw (i think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like fancybox extracts the `iframe` element from the DOM and puts it into it's own container. Then, when you close the fancybox, it attempts to insert it back where it originally was - but manages to loose the `src` attribute value.

The fancybox guy's approved method of opening an iframe seems to be the following.

```
<a id="mylink" class="iframe" href="frames/frame4.php">mylink</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mylink").fancybox();
</script>
```

One way to circumvent it, is to clone the iframe element, i.e.

```
function openIframeLink() {
    $.fancybox( {content: $('#data').clone()} );
}
```

Obviously not ideal.. I'd love hear someone more familiar chime in.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much.  It didn't quite do what I wanted (probably my fault) but you showed me exactly enough to fix the problem.
` function openIframeLink() {
 /* Grab the src before fancybox loses it*/
 theSrc = $("#data").attr('src');
 $.fancybox({
  'type'   : 'inline',
  'href'          : '#data',
  onClosed  : function(){
   $('#data').attr('src', theSrc);
  }
 });
};` --thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Had this same problem. Based on Frode's assessment that it was stripping the src attribute, I added the 'onClosed' callback on my fancybox call and was able to add it back in:

```
jQuery('#iframe_element').fancybox({
    'onClosed': reloadIframe
});

function reloadIframe() {
    jQuery('#iframe_element').attr('src','http://example.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox loses the src attribute.  Here is a workaround I've been using ever since

```
function openIframeLink() { 
    /* Grab the src before fancybox loses it */ 
    theSrc = $("#data").attr('src'); 
    $.fancybox({ 
        'type'     : 'inline', 
        'href'     : '#data', 
        onClosed     : function()
        { 
            $('#data').attr('src', theSrc); 
        } 
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of recovering the src attribute, without knowing the element beforehand.

Might help someone..

```
$(".fancybox.iframe").each(function(){
    var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
    var src = target.attr("src");
    $(this).fancybox({
        'type': "inline",
        'content': target,
        'onClosed': function(){
            target.attr("src", src);
        }
    });
});
```